# Scala - List of Strings to Square Cypher String

Tags: scala

I am following an exercise in Scala to build a square cypher. Here's an overview of the problem:

`List("hello", "world", "fille", "r")` is written taking the first letter from each `String` in the `List` and concatenating to the final string.  Essentially, if you write them in `square cypher` form, you get:

`hwfr
eoi
lrl
lll
ode`

Which if you read from top to bottom, left to right, is the message.  My expected output needs to be a `List[String]` that becomes `List("hwfr", "eoi", ...)`.  I don't know what methods or where to start in order to manipulate the original `List` in order to adhere to the form that I need.  I can't `map zip` since `zip` only takes two arguments and I have an indeterminate amount of `Strings`.  I'm not exactly sure how I might iterate over this `List` to get the result I need and would appreciate any suggestions or tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version which does not care about equal word length. There should be more efficient versions, but I wanted to keep it relatively short.

Basic idea: Find out how long the longest word is (`max`). Since you know that, you start with index `i = 0` and take the character at that position `i` from each string and form a string from it until you are at `i = max - 1` (which is the position of the last character of the longest word. When the words are not at equal length, you have to make sure that you don't access a character which is not there.

Example: `i = 1`, then you get `e` from `hello`, `o` from `world`, `i` from `fille`, but accessing character 1 on `r` would result in an exception. That is why we check for size of the string beforehand and in that case append the empty string. `if(i < elem.size) elem(i) else ""`

```
val list = List("hello", "world", "fille", "r")

val max = list.maxBy(_.size).size //gives you the size of the longest word

val result: List[String] = (0 until max).map(i => list.foldLeft("")
   ((s, elem) => s + (if(i < elem.size) elem(i) else "")))(collection.breakOut)

println(result) //List(hwfr, eoi, lrl, lll, ode)
```

Edit:

If you still want it to be readable from left-right/top-bottom (if they are not ordered by length and you don't want to order them), you can introduce spaces. Change `if(i < elem.size) elem(i) else ""` to `if(i < elem.size) elem(i) else " "`.

`List("hello", "world", "fille", "r")` would become `List(hwfr, eoi , lrl , lll , ode )` and `List("hello", "world", "r", "fille")` would become `List(hwrf, eo i, lr l, ll l, od e)`

Comment: This is wonderful, thank you very much for taking some time to work on this. It certainly looks better than what I had.

Comment: You are welcome. Although the words are kind of sorted by length in your example. If you change the order, the result can not quite be read. For example: `List("hello", "world", "r", "fille")`. Does it still work like you want it for that?

Comment: For my problem, the list is created with the words sorted by length, so this is a non-issue for me.

Comment: If your list is sorted by length, the `list.maxBy(_.size).size` is not needed, since the first word is the longest already and the list does not need to be traversed. You may change that to `val max = list.headOption.fold(0)(_.size)` if your list may be empty or `val max = list.head.size` if your list always has at least one element.

Answer (score 2):

```
scala> val list = List("hello", "world", "fille", "rtext")
list: List[String] = List(hello, world, fille, rtext)

scala> list.transpose
res6: List[List[Char]] = List(List(h, w, f, r), List(e, o, i, t), List(l, r, l, e), List(l, l, l, x), List(o, d, e, t))
```

does the trick, [api](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@transpose[B](implicitasTraversable:A=>scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B]):CC[CC[B]@scala.annotation.unchecked.uncheckedVariance])

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer!  The only issue I have is that `transpose` requires all the lists have the same size.  This is not always the case (but can happen).  I edited my original post to rid the illusion that the lists will have evenly partitioned sections.

Comment: I managed to write the method using transpose.  It's not pretty, but it works.  Thank you for giving me a start in the right direction!